# Failed login attempts in Oracle within what time frame?

Tags: oracle, c3p0

I'm trying to configure a [C3P0 JDBC connection pool](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) to avoid locking an Oracle DB. Seems like `acquireRetryAttempts` and `acquireRetryDelay` are important.

Looking at [Oracle 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6012.htm#SQLRF01310) docs, I see:

```
FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS  
Specify the number of consecutive failed attempts to log in to the user account before the account is locked. If you omit this clause, then the default is 10 times.
```

Within what time frame do the 10 attempts apply? I.e. if I set `acquireRetryAttempts` to `9`, what value of `acquireRetryDelay` will avoid locking the DB?

Comment: I wouldn't expect that the two are related.  Normally, you'd use a service account in your connection pool.  Normally, that service account's password would not change (or would be rotated as part of a change controlled operation).  So database connection failures from a connection pool would not generally be failed logins, they would normally be the result of network hiccups, the database being down, etc.  Retries would only cause the account to be locked if, say, you're using a password to authenticate the account, the password changed, and no one updated the app server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for a time frame after which Oracle will forget about previous invalid login attempts?  There is none.

Oracle maintains a column `lcount` in the `SYS.USER$` table that has the number of consecutive invalid login attempts.  It is only reset to zero upon a successful login.

If you don't want to lock the database accounts for too many failed password attempts, why don't you set `failed_login_attempts` to `UNLIMITED` for the profile your connection pool uses?

Comment: Unfortunately we don't control the profile settings for the DB, but thanks for clarifying--what you say makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has [Universal Connection Pool (UCP)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjucp/toc.htm) that is feature rich and provides HA capabilities out of the box. So, you could consider using UCP.

Also, RETRY_DELAY and RETRY_COUNT can be used as connection descriptors as shown.

(DESCRIPTION =
     (CONNECT_TIMEOUT=90)  (RETRY_COUNT=20)(RETRY_DELAY=3) (TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3) 
       (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (LOAD_BALANCE=on)
        ( ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST=primary-scan)(PORT=1521)))
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
         (LOAD_BALANCE=on)
        ( ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST=secondary-scan)(PORT=1521)))
       (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME = gold-cloud)))

RETRY_COUNT:It specifies the number of network connect retry attempts before returning a failure message to the client.  In the example above, Oracle Net retries 3 times before returning an error message to the client.  This helps in increasing the possibility of getting a connection and thus improves the performance.
RETRY_DELAY:This parameter specifies the wait time in seconds between reconnection 
attempts. It works in conjunction with RETRY_COUNT. So, it is advised to use RETRY_DELAY and RETRY_COUNT together to avoid unnecessary CPU cycles